# BASH: How can I check if the Environmental variables comprising an array exist?

Tags: arrays, bash, element, exists

I have an array:

```
arr=($A $B)
```

I want to make sure that A and B are both existing.  How can I do this?  Without manually checking each and every element before the array declaration?

Answer (score 3):

When expanding a shell variable that might be unset, you have the following options: You can substitute a default for an unset value; you can set the variable to a default and then substitute it; or you can raise an error.

Here are the details from the bash manual:

> `${parameter:-word}`
>            Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion
>            of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of  parameter is
>            substituted.
>
> `${parameter:=word}`
>                 Assign  Default  Values.   If  parameter  is  unset or null, the
>                 expansion of word is assigned to parameter.  The value of parameter 
>                 is  then  substituted.   Positional parameters and special
>                 parameters may not be assigned to in this way.
>
> `${parameter:?word}`
>                 Display Error if Null or Unset.  If parameter is null or  unset,
>                 the  expansion  of  word (or a message to that effect if word is
>                 not present) is written to the standard error and the shell,  if
>                 it is not interactive, exits.  Otherwise, the value of parameter
>                 is substituted.

So if you want to raise an error, the simplest use is as follows. You can add a custom message after the question mark:

```
% echo ${UNSET?}
-bash: UNSET: parameter null or not set
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want it might be sufficient to supply a default value for `A` and `B`

```
arr=("${A:-one}" "${B:-two}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell option for generating an error on *any* use of an unset variable, but it might be too general for your use case.

```
$ set -u
$ A=6
$ arr=($A $B)
bash: B: unbound variable
```